# change password of mysql in Centos 6.5

Tags: mysql

I installed mysql as follows :

```
sudo yum install mysql-server
```

I installed mysql-server on cents 6.5 which did not give me any password
so when I use it as

I try to follow these steps

1) sudo service mysqld stop
2) sudo mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables &
3) mysql -uroot

4) user mysql;

**The error is Error 1049 (42000) unknown database mysql;**

4)UPDATE user SET Password=PASSWORD('NewPassHere') WHERE User='root';
or 
update user set password=PASSWORD("mynewpassword") where User='root';

4.2) FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
4.3) quit;
5) sudo service mysqld restart

Comment: Please edit your question to include your complete steps on how you installed the MySQL server. Also include the tutorial/walkthrough/manual you used to install the MySQL server. That the `mysql` database is missing is not a good sign since the users are stored in the `mysql.user` table.

Comment: @Progman I just installed it with yum , look at above . what do you think ?